# Twinge of (a) thought

Tags: sentence-construction, articles, indefinite-article

> I didn't pay attention to that twinge of (a) thought of losing what I hadn't lost yet.

Should there be an article in this phrase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say yes, it needs an article.

A 'twinge' is a sudden sharp pain. It is not being used here as a measurement of thought, like you would say "a moment of time". It is saying that the thought *was like* a twinge, that it occurred suddenly and sharply. So "a twinge of a thought" is syntactically similar to expressions like "a giant of **a** man", in which a man is being *likened* to a giant.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Astralbee that an article is needed, but I am surprised nobody has mentioned the definite article. The definite article would sound better in this context

> I didn't pay attention to that twinge of *the* thought of losing what I hadn't lost yet.